# how do you catch a 'click' on a {{linkTo}} using a view?

Tags: ember.js

*(Note: I am using Ember version 1.0.0-rc.3)*

I'm trying to catch the 'click' of a `{{linkTo}}` using a view, so that I can do additional stuff (basically scroll the list of users in the sidebar) besides merely loading the new template. Me being relatively new to this (but having read the documentation!), I thought the following would just work:

**"users" template:**

```
{{#each user in users}}
    {{#view App.ClickView}}
        {{#linkTo user user}}{{ user.name }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

**the view code:**

```
App.ClickView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(evt) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

and for context, the **layout template:**

```
<div id='sidebar'>
    {{#each user in users}}
        {{#linkTo user user}}{{ user.name }}{{/linkTo}}
    {{/each}}
</div>

<div id='main'>
    {{ outlet }}
</div>
```

Referring back to the **users template**, you can see that each `{{linkTo}}` is contained within a view. I'm expecting for a click on that {{linkTo}} to therefore bubble up to, and caught by the view (`App.ClickView`). Unfortunately, it doesn't. It seems like the click is somehow not being bubbled up to the view when it's happens on a `{{linkTo}}`... What should I do?

**Note #1**:
If I replace the `{{linkTo}}` (**only** in div#main! I don't intend to replace the ones in div#sidebar) with an `<a>` element, it works, and the click gets caught by the view. However, I'm not so sure that i want to go down this route (I'd have to replicate the functionality of the `{{linkTo}}`!). And I'm thinking that there ought to be a better way to do this. Is there?

**Note #2**:
*Note that I'm also aware that i can put my intended "do stuff" code in renderTemplate() of the UserRoute, but the problem with that is that the effect will happen for every link to that route (including the ones in the sidebar - which is not what I want). I want the scroll to *only trigger for specific `{{linkTo}}`s - specifically the `{{linkTo}}`s in div#main.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an anchor (<a>) tag with `{{action ... target="view"}}` in it instead of linkTo, apply your conditional logic in the view, and then if appropriate, re-send to the controller (`this.get('controller').send(actionName)`, let it bubble to the router, and do a transitionTo in a router event handler.

Comment: I assume you're saying to resend to the controller only because you need to to send it to the router? (rather than because you're suggesting to have the controller handle the action, in which case it wouldnt bubble up to the router).

Also: specific to my use case, would you know if there's any way to find the route given a model? So in my case, I wont be replacing the `linkTo`s in the sidebar with `<a>` elements (which is what I'd have to do to use `{{ action ... }}`). And I would like to find the correct linkTo using _something_ like `$('a[href="model.route"]')`.

Comment: I agree with Luke here. Linkto is for transitioning an setting context. Events will not be handled the way you wish. On the other hand, I do not understand why the answer provided by Luke is not good.

Comment: @Jeffrey'jf'Lim yes, send to the controller because your view shouldn't be concerned with who will ultimately handle the action. Your implementation will let it bubble to the router where you will handle it. I don't have the context to answer your other question. Maybe it deserves its own SO question?

Comment: @LukeMelia, I've editted the question. It's much easier to read now, and I hope the context is much clearer. I suppose I could take out the question about locating the `{{linkTo}}` in the sidebar into its own SO question; but since it's so integral to the main question, and is the reason why I even ask this main question in the first place...

Comment: @EduárdMoldován "Events will not be handled the way you wish." what? Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I can imagine that link-to is a lot easier than  faffing about passing messages up the component hierarchy just so that you can call transitionToRoute